# Get a label value from a div and show it in html

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

Hi I want to get a label value from a div and show it in an html div tag. I'm building an html5 video player with playlist and so far as soon as I click on the thumbnail the video changes and also it is adding a different label each time to a div. I want to print that label in the html and change it each time a new video is showing. I've tried a few things but cannot get it to work. jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zo8tcuxs/1/

my code is:

```
<section id="video-container">
    <video id="videoarea" controls="controls" poster="" src="" id="video1" ></video>
<div id="description" label="" type="text"> </div>
<ul id="playlist">
    <li id="videoweek1" movieurl="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" label="This is video number 1 " type="video/mp4" moviesposter="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/screen.jpg">
    <img src="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/screen.jpg" class="video-thumbnail">
</li>
    <li id="videoweek2" movieurl="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" label="This is video number 2 " type="video/mp4" > <img src="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/screen.jpg" class="video-thumbnail"></li> 
</ul>
</section>

$(function() {
    $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
        $("#videoarea").attr({
            "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
            "poster": "",
            "autoplay": "autoplay"
        })
    })
    $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
        $("#description").attr({
            "label": $(this).attr("label")
        })
    })
    $("#videoarea").attr({
        "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
        "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
    })



})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `.text()`/`.html()` of the target `div` element.

```
    $("#description").attr({
        "label": $(this).attr("label")
    }).text($(this).attr("label"))
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/L2xjxgjd/)

Answer (score 0):

Label do not have value, it have html under `> html here </` (opening and closing tag). Try this:

```
$( function() {
    var lblTxt = $('#label').html();
    $('#div').html(lblTxt);
});
```

HTML

```
<label id="label">Hello</label>

<div id="div">
</div>
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66bw5u4h/53/)